# Putting specific values of vector the rows of matrix

Tags: r, vector, matrix

I have a vector like this :

```
Sum<-c(24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 28, 36, 44, 52, 60)
```

now i want to make a matrix of this vector like the first 5 values of the vector should become the first row of the matrix and the rest five as second row like this.

```
 1   2  3  4  5
1 24  32 40 48 56
2 28  36 44 52 60
```

when i use the matrix function it gives me output like this which i don't want:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   24   40   56   36   52
[2,]   32   48   28   44   60
```

Is there a way to get the desired output??
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `byrow` parameter of matrix

```
m <- matrix(Sum, nrow=2, byrow=T)
```

See `?matrix` for more help

Comment: Thanks.i forgot the byrow arguement.